# Won't boot if USB stuff is plugged in?

Tags: boot, grub2, mouse

Edit: it fixed itself, but I have no idea how...

I have a new laptop running Ubuntu 11.04.  If I have certain USB devices (a wireless mouse, or my camera, but not a USB flash drive) plugged in to any of the computer's USB ports, Ubuntu won't boot.  (They work fine as long as I plug them in once I can see an Ubuntu splash screen.)  It gets to GRUB, and if I run in recovery mode, it starts booting, then freezes at about 2 seconds, and goes to a black screen.  (Without recovery mode, it just does the black screen.)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does nothing; I also can't ssh into it at this point.  Removing kernel options `quiet splash` from GRUB did nothing except give a "Loading, please wait..." message with the USB not plugged in; the same for replacing them with `noapic`.  My BIOS has no "legacy USB" option that I can find.

Nothing I can find in /var/log is updated when this happens, so I have no logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check logfiles for errors? (`/var/log/boot.log` and `/var/log/boot` for instance). Re-installing `grub` might be an option.

Comment: I see no errors, but that may be because they're being overwritten when I reboot again (with mouse unplugged to get back to a useable system).

Comment: Boot, wait for it to crash. Turn system of and then use a live cd to look at `/var/log`. That way your log files should be useable IF the system even gets there to write an error  ;)

Comment: Tried that; all of the files are from the boots before the crash.  I assume it's not getting to the point where it writes the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the folllowing: You could disbale the USB ports until the boot ends and then activate the USB ports: I think you could do this via vim.

```
cd /etc/default
sudo vim acpi-support
Change the module line the following:
MODULES="usbcore"
```

I am **really** not sure if this works and if this has the consequence that your USB ports doesn't work anymore  I will not take that on me. I would recommend this solution only experts who could redo this. Only works if you got usbcore. Some peaople haven't got it.
You should first test if you have got it:

```
$ ls -l /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/usb/usbcore.o*
```

Could also work with this folder: /usr/src/linux-your-version/drivers/usb

This could work because: If you start ubuntu your usb devices are of course off but after the boot they should of course be activated like after a suspend. I had this problems ones with an laptop. ***It would also be very cool if you tell us your exactly laptop model because it could have other reasons.***

Answer (score 0):

Your do nousb as grub boot command and activate it after boot but I don't know how to. Or maybe easier disable acpi support and do a quit splash should work with: `ro quiet splash noapic`